# Assign existing column based on multiple conditions -- python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python and I'm learning by writing old codes in R over to Python. I have this dataframe with many different columns that each have ranges based on sex and age for each row. I want to select the appropriate sex-age range based on two other columns that have sex and age separately

here's a dummy df, but there are multiple rows all with the same individual's data.

```
sex age malechild maleadult maleold femalechild femaleadult femaleold
M   63  0-1       0-2       0-3     0-0.9       0-1.9       0-2.9
M   63  0-2       0-4       0-6     0-1.9       0-2.9       0-3.9
```

I want to create a new column that would select the correct column for the sex-age range but everything I've tried hasn't worked. I tried using if/elif/else; setting conditions and outputs; np.select; np.where and I'm lost!
In R, I would use dplyr's mutate and case_when but I don't think that translates well to python when mixing numerics and strings. Any ideas?

This is the output I'm going for (note there are many other cols in this df and that I can easily drop all the other columns after the initial assigning step but I'm used to creating a new column rather than just selecting one. And ideally this would be reproducible for any sex/age)

```
sex age range
M   63  0-3
M   63  0-6
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with specific function applied on column axis (`1`):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# df = pd.DataFrame(...)  your df

def find_range_bounds(r, s_map):
    col_sufix = 'old'
    if 6 <= r['age'] < 20:
        col_suffix = 'child'
    elif 20 <= r['age'] < 60:
        col_suffix = 'adult'
    return r[sex_map[r['sex']] + col_sufix]

sex_map = {'M': 'male', 'F': 'female'}
df['range'] = df.apply(find_range_bounds, s_map=sex_map, axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

```
  sex  age malechild maleadult maleold femalechild femaleadult femaleold range
0   M   63       0-1       0-2     0-3       0-0.9       0-1.9     0-2.9   0-3
1   M   63       0-2       0-4     0-6       0-1.9       0-2.9     0-3.9   0-6
```

Comment: I tried that on my df and got an error: ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 16 has 0 dimension(s)

Comment: @Colleen, but you have not presented the rules for `ages` before your last edit

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result in Python using the Pandas library. You can create a function to select the appropriate range based on the 'sex' and 'age' columns and then apply this function to create a new 'range' column in your DataFrame. If you want the code try to ask at chatgpt.